# YII2 ЧПУ урл с alias

Tags: yii2, nginx, alias, slug

Всем добрый вечер. Прошу информационной помощи. Сайт на YII2, на сервере только nginx, апача нет. Конфиг нжинкса прописал, вроде все норм, но я на сайте использую алиасы (slug)и у меня ну прям никак не получается привести ссылки в нормальный вид. Если обычный ссылки `/site/catalog` не вызывают нареканий, то `/rig?alias=tip-dvigatelya-8nvd48` а уж тем более `?alias=tip-dvigatelya-8nvd48&page=2` не дают покоя. Правила в urlmanager писал разные, ничего хорошего не получилось. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Конструкция 
`'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<alias>' => '<controller>/<action>'`, помогла привести ссылку к виду `/category/index/nasosy/`. Может кто подсказать как из нее убрать/скрыть `/index`?

Comment: Почему нельзя было сразу ЧПУ делать?

Comment: Можно подробней?

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны использовать запись в `urlManager` вида:

```
 '/category/<slug>' => '/category/index'
```

в контроллере в свою очередь : `public function actionIndex($slug = null)`
и по значению параметра `$slug` ввытаскивать категорию.